# What is the best option to do session management in Express Js application?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a express js application. I will host this application in cloud foundry across multiple servers.
I am looking for any suggest on which option should I use for session management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try express-session module. You can try storing session in database.
[express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Answer (score -1):

1. It is an official package from the Express core team. Whether or not it's "good" for production is subjective.
2. There is a plethora of compatible session stores available as stated in the readme: https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores. Pick the one that's most appropriate for your use case.